# Graph API: converted doc file to docx

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive

Our application uses graph api to edit a file in oneDrive and show the edited content inside the application.  The problem is some of the word files are in old word format, if user edits those files, the files needs to be converted to docx. For example:

- a user want to edit file testfile.doc then s/he clicks on filename inside the application, the file will be open in oneDrive
- in order to edit the file, user should convert the file to newer version (see attached image)
- then the new file is created in onedrive: testfile.docx.
- user makes her changes in this file.
- since it is a new file, now the application doesn't know about it. So the file changes won't reflect in application.

I cannot think of any solution for this. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, the above behavior is expected, if you're using older .doc file in web. This issue is already documented at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-compatibility-mode-in-word-for-the-web-03ff7a17-a32d-42f7-81a9-f65a4b270795

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late to answer here and TS will not benefit from my answer however I will describe here the solution we implemented as we faced the same problem.

The converted file always gets the original file name and only extension is changed (e.g. .doc to .docx). So once your user opens somefile.doc for edit you start monitoring files on Sharepoint site (by calling `graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();`) every N second. You get the list of files and check if it contains somefile.docx. Once it appears in results you get its ID and you can now track changes and do all the kind of things with it according to your requirements.